# Google has changed Linkify implementation with custom links in Android 5

Tags: android, linkify

We've got some custom links in our application that look like that `bar.foo://var?parameter=value`

Prior Android 5.0.0 `bar.foo` was not recognised as a link. However in Android 5.0.0 it is recognized as a link and Android will try to open it in the default browser if you click anywhere on `bar.foo:`. If you however click on `//var?parameter=value` it will treat it as a customized link and do the stuff that is intended.

Is there any way to prevent this?

This is our Linkify related code:

```
Linkify.addLinks(this, Linkify.WEB_URLS); // This one is causing the issue. Unfortunately we can't disable it

for (final Pattern pattern : linkPatterns) {
    Linkify.addLinks(this, pattern, linkPrefix);
}
```

Comment: I am skeptical as to your conclusion that "this one is causing the issue", based upon my reading of [the source code to `Linkify`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/util/Linkify.java) and [the source code to  `Patterns.WEB_URL`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/util/Patterns.java). I don't see anything in there that would cause it to recognize `bar.foo`,  unless you are doing so yourself in your `Linkify.addLinks(this, pattern, linkPrefix)` code.

Comment: If I comment the line `Linkify.addLinks(this, Linkify.WEB_URLS);` out then everything works fine and I can click anywhere on our custom links.

Comment: :: shrug :: Then don't use `Linkify.addLinks(this, Linkify.WEB_URLS)`, and instead handle them yourself, via manual `addLinks()` calls akin to your `addLinks(this, pattern, linkPrefix)`, or by introducing the necessary spans in other ways (e.g., `SpannableString` methods). `Linkify` is convenience code; there is nothing that `Linkify` does that you cannot do yourself. Or, fork `Linkify` and fix it to fit your needs. I don't see an [outstanding issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=linkify) that matches your symptoms, though I haven't done a deep investigation of them.